# How can I check in jQuerys $.ajax callback 'complete' if an request was successful?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a big code blocks in my ajax `complete` callback where I want to check if an ajax request was successful or not:

```
$.ajax(function() {
    url: 'http://hostname.com',
    data: myData,
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(data) {

        // [... much code ...]

        $('#MyElement').text(<success> ? $.parseJSON(data.responseText) : 'Failed');

        // [... much code ...]
    }
});
```

My problem: I want to keep my code DRY and do not want copy the code into 'success' and 'error' callbacks. So what can I use for my placeholder `<success>` here?

Comment: You will get the status as a second argument... so `function(data, textStatus)` then you can check whether it is `'error'`

Comment: Your syntax for ajax method is completly wrong. I guess this is typo in question but you should make some effort to post a relevant question to your issue

Comment: @A. Wolff: You are right. I have fixed the typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a second argument in your setting:

```
complete: function(data, status) { ... }
```

`status` will then contain one of the following values:

- "success"
- "notmodified"
- "error"
- "timeout"
- "abort"
- "parsererror"

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method does not have a callback function as parameter.  You should pass the `url` or an object, or both.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

**complete**
Type: Function( [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) jqXHR, String textStatus )

> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

You can use the second argument `textStatus` by modifying your function like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myUrl',
  data: {myData: myData},
  complete: function(data, status) {
    $('#MyElement').text(status=="success"? data : "Failed");
  }
});
```